# Android BottomNavigation and MapView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mapview

I'm trying to implement the first Activity of an app with the BottomNavigation. This will have three tabs whose will open three different fragments.

The landing fragment is a MapView then you can access to the other fragments so for it I replace them.

```
private void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();


    if(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag) != null) {

        fragmentManager.popBackStack(tag, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    }else {

        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.framelayout_home_content, fragment, tag);
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

Every time I replace my fragment and go back to the Map the map is built again. Is there any way to keep the Map or speed up the process in order to avoid flickr every time it is shown?

should I addToBackStack and then Pop It up?

Indeed I already tried it but I don't think I've done it right

```
private void showSearchMap() {

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) return;

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
}
```

in order to avoid open a fragment once it is already visible:

if( getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.framelayout_home_content)
                instanceof SettingsFragment ) return;

Is there any proper way to handle this BottomNavigation with Fragments?